# how to transfer object data from express route to jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, post

I'm wondering if I can transfer the object data from the html view which is rendered from the server side route("res.render('view', {title: 'title', object: object_data})") to jquery.
The reason why I asked this is I want to use this object on the other route which is triggered
by click function which is controlled by jquery.

I tried to make a jquery code like below, but it didn't work...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     $("#option0").click(function() {
        $.get('/other_route', {
            flag: 'all' data: object});
```

please help me TT

and, this is what I made the object

```
exports.search_post =  [

    sanitizeBody('location').escape(),
    sanitizeBody('style').escape(),
    sanitizeBody('dateFrom').toDate(),
    sanitizeBody('dateTo').toDate(),

    (req, res, next) => {

    var reserv = new Reservation(
        {
            start_date: req.body.dateFrom,
            end_date: req.body.dateTo,
            customer: null,
            car: null,
            reservation_no: null,
        }
    )

    async.parallel({

        cars: function(callback) {
                Car.find()
             .where('available_date')
             .gte(reserv.start_date)
             .lt(reserv.end_date)
             .exec(callback);

            },
        }, function(err, results) {
            if(err) {return next(err);}
            if(results==null) {
                var err = new Error('Car not found');
                err.status = 404;
                return next(err);
            }
            res.render('car_list', {title: 'Available List', object: results.cars});

        });
    }
]
```

Comment: Where/how is `object` defined?

Comment: Keep in mind, express runs on the server.  jQuery runs on the client.  So asking how to give a client script data from a server script, is inheriently going to require you to give us more information about how the two are interacting.

Comment: I added what I did to get the object. please check

Comment: I'm assuming that backend logic preceeds the client logic.  How exactly does the process flow work that it goes through that backend logic and then arrives at the client page that would then have the client script that you want to give information to?

Comment: so the object data is loaded on the view 'car_list' first, and then jquery code is working after users click the #option0 button. and I wanna transfer this object data to the other routers and then re-organize it, and render it on same page again, like filter button.